# Ubuntu 20.04LTS black screen after installation

Tags: 20.04, intel-nuc

I have just installed Ubuntu Desktop 20.04LTS on a Intel NUC 8 (NUC8i3BEH).

The USB installer worked perfectly, but after rebooting, I am getting a black screen right after the grub, with no text, and selecting recovery mode gets stuck on "loading initial ramdisk" forever.

I have tried editing the boot parameters, adding i915.modeset=0 but the black screen still persists.

Any suggestion?

Machine: Intel NUC8i3BEH
Memory size: 64GB
Storage: M.2 2280 SSD 2TB
Bios: uEFI, secure boot OFF.

In the BIOS, both memory and M.2 SSD are properly recognized.
When I boot from USB and click on "Try Ubuntu", Ubuntu boots and is working fine. But it always goes to black screen right after GRUB once installed.

Comment: Thanks Karel! But it did not help. I tried "nomodeset" in the GRUB screen but still got a black screen. I also tried "apci=off nolapic", which did not work either.

Comment: I converted uEFI to legacy BIOS and re-installed Ubuntu 20.04. This time it booted from m.2 ssd without an issue.